# Converting super class to specific derived type

Tags: c#, java, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I have an inheritance hierarchy with a super class named `Transaction`. I am using it as a variable in one of my classes but I am having trouble converting it to specific types, such as `GameTransaction`, `ScienceTransaction` etc..

Each specific type has specific attributes, so I have to check if it is that type via `typeof` then cast it, so I end up with `If.. else if..` and so on depending on how many derived classes there are for `Transaction`.

This is annoying. Is there any other way around this? Any design pattern for this?

Comment: Sounds like a design issue. Separate your code that works on generalized `Transaction`s from the code that works on `GameTransaction` etc. The caller of the more speific code ought to know the type of transaction it is dealing with. Of course, it's hard to say for sure without seeing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why did you tag this with both `c#` and `java`? Which are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys im using c# but incase java programmers experience this so at least.. Griffey my super class transaction is being used in my facade(design pattern) class so everytime there are methods or service that involve or require casting to a specific type I suffer the If.. Else IF.. Else IF.... checking then casting to specific type to access that property or attribute any other way?

Answer (score 1):

If a method is accepting a parameter of Transaction, behavior in that method should be at that level. If that method is using data that could be different on GameTransaction, ScienceTransaction etc, that data must be available through an access method at the Transaction level. Each specializations could override that access method and provide that additional data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Aragorn. so your saying that if i have a method: MyGameMethod specific to GameTransaction class I should also put it in the abstract class Transaction? so if i have say 4 sub classes inheriting from Transaction i should put all methods specific to each class to the base class as abstract or virtual methods? would'nt that make the base class big? as in many methods some may not be usefull to other derived type only to a specific one.. like MyGameMethod.. would it be okay?

Comment: @user2080671: No, you only offer methods on `Transaction` that apply to *any* transaction. If you need a method that is only available on one type/subclass of transaction, then the method must only accept that subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If a method requires a `GameTransaction`, you must pass it a `GameTransaction`.

Passing in a variable of type `Transaction` and casting it to `GameTransaction` is bad design - it's hard to understand, and a source of programming mistakes: If you accidentally pass the wrong type, the compiler cannot spot this for you.

If you really have methods that are supposed to work on any type of transaction (generic methods, so to say), then `Transaction` must expose sufficient information for these methods.

For example, if a method is supposed to check when a transation was started, then you must have a method like `Transaction.startTime()`, not just `GameTransaction.startTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

> my super class transaction is being used in my facade(design pattern) class so everytime there are methods or service that involve or require casting to a specific type I suffer the If.. Else IF.. Else IF.... checking then casting to specific type to access that property or attribute

yes.. that was the problem when using facade pattern. you need to do extra cast on the client code.

consider to use [Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on you facade

```
public class Facade
{
    public Transaction GetTransaction<T>() where T : Transaction
    {
        // any other process
        return (T)result;
    }
}
```

simply call it on the client code:

```
GameTransaction gameTx = facadeInstance.GetTransaction<GameTransaction>();
```

another option to facade pattern is using dependency injection. so rather than create a big class that share on every code, you provide a *system* for creating objects and its dependency. and that will be a long story to explain :)